# How to fit all the TextView in custom size

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android deve;p[,emt. I apologize for the bad English. I have a question for displaying text in `LinearLayout`. `LinearLayout` has a size I set 350x230 dp. There are 10 pieces `TextView`. When I fill a `TextView` text, then install them yet, and size, each TextView can have your text size. How can you fit all the TextView in my LinearLayout? If you can - then help with the code. Here is my activity xml:

**XML Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0e0a2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearCard"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.jaganat.vizicard.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#fff" >
        </com.jaganat.vizicard.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA Class:**

```
public class CardView extends LinearLayout {
    private View view;

    public CardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init(context);
    }
    public CardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        init(context);
    }
    private void init(Context context){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view,this);
    }
    }
```

my card_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tFirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tFirm2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tJob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tJob2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tFIO"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tFIO2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tOffice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tOffice2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tTel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tMob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tFax"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tTelH"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tAddress2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tWWW"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you also post card_view.xml please?

Comment: do you have limit for the length of each textview?

Comment: I think the length is not more than 250 characters

Comment: The only thing which comes to my mind is `android:weight=0.1` for each TextView, to give each View the same amount of space.